# Error 403: Forbidden when I try to connect to server OAuth 2.0

Tags: c#, oauth, office365

I am working in a booking app which was working since Microsoft decided to erase the old connection method (EWS API connection without OAuth) to retrieve info about an Outlook calendar.

I have what is shown below, copied from Microsoft forums:

```
protected async Task<ExchangeService> exchangeService(string roomEmail)
        {
            var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appId"])
                .WithClientSecret(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"])
                .WithTenantId(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"])
                .Build();

            var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };

            try
            {
                var authResult = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);

                // Configure the ExchangeService with the access token
                var ewsClient = new ExchangeService();
                ewsClient.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
                ewsClient.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);
                ewsClient.ImpersonatedUserId =
                    new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, roomEmail);

                //Include x-anchormailbox header
                ewsClient.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", roomEmail);

                return ewsClient;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                connecting.Text = e.ToString();
                loadingScreen(true, false, false, false, true, true, false, true);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I've followed all the steps but the result is an "Error 403: forbidden".

As far as I know, this happens when the account you are requesting to doesn't have permissions to access the services, but all the accounts I want to retrieve calendars from have permissions in the AAD.

What can I do? I am blocked and I don't know how to solve this problem, help will be appreciated

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using confidential client then make sure you have given the permission with "Application" type and not delegated.
"full_access_as_app" this permission will give the access to mailbox and it will need admin approval first then only it will be available to use. In fact all application level permission will need admin approval.

Comment: It was the problem! At the next day I found the solution giving "full_acces_as_app" permission. 

Also I had to create an ApplicationAccessPolicy in PowerShell to restrict the mail accounts I want to grant access to the app.

Thanks for the reply!